# How to install Turbo C++ Explorer 2006 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

### What I would like to do

I would like to use my free compiler suite, Turbo C++ Explorer 2006 (I'll call here by "Turbo"), because I still have about 91 years of license to use it :)

### The issue

Below I put the steps to install prerequisites.

After prerequisites are installed on a machine with Windows XP, I can install Turbo normally.

But when trying to install on Windows 7, when launching Turbo installer, it shows an error that 3rd prerequisite below is not installed and exit.

### Steps to install prerequisites

1. Microsoft Internet Explorer v6.0 SP1: FAIL (alert: not designed for 64-bit)
2. Microsoft .NET Framework v1.1: OK
3. Microsoft .NET Framework v1.1 SP1: FAIL (alert: not recognizing installed Microsoft .NET Framework v1.1)
4. Microsoft .NET Framework SDK v1.1: OK
5. Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML) v4.0 SP2: OK
6. Microsoft Visual J# .NET v1.1 Redistributable: OK

Comment: Did you try running it in compatibility mode? Since you have Windows 7, have you tried it in XP Mode?  Have you contacted the authors regarding updating to a version that's actually compatible with your chosen OS?

Comment: I'm trying the answer of http://superuser.com/questions/120218/how-do-i-install-net-framework-1-1-for-windows-7

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I already tried it, with no solution :(

Comment: Use the Windows XP Mode (XP VM) to run incompatible tools like this one

Comment: @magicandre1981 I used solution of above link with some more procedures and it solved. I'm testing the result before answering here because I encountered some side effects, like I can open only one instance of software per Windows session - I have to restart Windows to open it again; no logoff :'(