# "This patch package could not be open" when installing .Net 1.1 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, .net-framework, windows-installer

I must install .Net 1.1 on Windows 7, so I am using [this procedure](https://superuser.com/a/120239/22536) (which is also the procedure [recommended by Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/article/jp/ja/jpbsd1/sln293924/how-to-install-net-framework-11-in-windows-7?lang=en)).

Problem: When I ran `dotnetfxsp1.exe /Xp:C:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp` nothing happened, and in particular no file was created in `C:\DotNet`. And the next command `msiexec.exe /a c:\DotNet\netfx.msi /p c:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp` failed with this message:

[image: This patch package could not be opened. Verify that the patch package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer patch package]

What did I do wrong?

I am on Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit, and this is the content of my `C:\DotNet` folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running these two commands a second time, the error did not occur again:

```
dotnetfxsp1.exe /Xp:C:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp
msiexec.exe /a c:\DotNet\netfx.msi /p c:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp
```

The first one does not make any dialog appear, only a spinner appears. The second command makes a progress dialog appear and then disappear within seconds with no error message.

Now just run the generated `netfx.msi` installer.